# How can I clear multiple bits at once in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How would I simplify all of this into one line?

```
    REG &= ~BITA;
    REG &= ~BITB;
    REG &= ~BITC;
    REG &= ~BITD;
    REG &= ~BITE;
```

Comment: Any C textbook should cover how to set, clear, toggle and test bits. Also imagine it in binary: Ones on the right side keep the bit value, zeroes clear the bit value. Just use as many bits as you like, but not more than the left side can store.

Comment: This is a mega duplicate. Why was it answered? It should have been closed. What is the canonical question?

Comment: Some candidates: *[How to replace bits in a bitfield without affecting other bits using C (2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5925755)*, and *[How do you set only certain bits of a byte in C without affecting the rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4439078)* (2010)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `|` (bitwise or) operator.

```
REG &= ~(BITA | BITB | BITC | BITD | BITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

@MikeCAT answer is correct and here is bit
There is a simple rule `A & B = ~A || ~B`. so you can extend your problem to:

```
REG &= ~BITA & ~BITB & ~BITC & ~BITD & ~BITE; // 10 operations
```

you can reduce it to:

```
REG &= ~(BITA | BITB | BITC | BITD | BITE);  // 6 operation
```

This way you factor out common factor to reduce number of operations. You can think of this retuction like math:

```
A += B * -55 + C * -55 + D * -55
A += -55B - 55C - 55D
A += -55(B + C + D)
```

To read more about boolean algebra (which is very important in this case [click here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html)

If I find any more good reference, I will link it here.

Comment: Reduction of operations can also be done during optimization at compile time. Sometimes it is better to write extended (more) instructions in cause of better readiness. Reduction of processing operations will only happen if the bits are not changed during runtime. If the bits are constant the preprocessor will change `~((1<<7) | (1<<6))` to `0b0011_1111` so the operation `REG &= ~(BITA | ...)` will take around 3 instructions after compiling.

Comment: @sunriax I agree Idk what compiler is OP using? And I kind of extended on MikCAT's answer

Comment: Is reduction standard?

Comment: i can not exactly say that every preprocessor simplifies constants automatically and compiler do optimization, but in environments i use `optimization level (O1)` is mostly turned on.

Comment: @sunriax in essence I do agree with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to clear bits by position with bit shifting:

```c
REG &= ~((1<<7) | (1<<6) | ...);
```

or with predefined bit position:

```c
#define BITA 7
#define BITB 6

REG &= ~((1<<BITA) | (1<<BITB) | ...);
```