# How to set masked bits to a specified number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I haven't been able to find an answer to this on Google, nor do I have any better search ideas.  If I have a 2 byte number, a mask, and a third number, how do I replace the masked bits with the third number.  For example if I have 0xABCD, the mask 0x0F00, and third number 4 - I would like to replace B with 4 to get A4CD.  In other words, I want to be able to replace arbitrary bits selected by a mask with the bits of another arbitrary number (we are assuming that the number replacing the bits fits - i.e. if I mask 5 bits, the number to replace those 5 bits requires 5 bits or less to represent.)

Comment: [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)?

Comment: It totaly not clear what you want to archive.

Comment: `(0xABCD & 0xF000)|0x0400` will do it. But it's not clear exactly what your full requirements are and whether that meets the need.

Comment: @kaylum - that gives 0xA400 - I am trying to get 0xA4CD (in this example) - so far I have come up with VALUE & (~MASK & 0xFFFF) | REPLACEMENT_BITS.  But lets say I only specify 4 - how do I determine from the mask that I need to put the 4 in the 3rd byte: f(value, mask, number) = value with masked bits replaced by number.  In my example, (0xABCD & (~0x0F00 & 0xFFFF)) | 0x400.

Comment: @tenspd137: you asked a fair question.  You need to 1) shift the source bits, then 2) replace the target bits, 3) As you anticipated, you also need a bitmask so you can preserve the source bits you're not replacing.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925794/421195

Comment: Yeah - AND the original value with the inverse of the bitmask - that gets you all the swap-bits set to zero.  AND the replace value with the mask, that gets the bits to be inserted only.  OR together and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to replace the bits of `number` selected by `mask` with those of `value`, shifted appropriately, assuming `value` does not exceed the target range.

Masking off the target bits is easy: `number &= ~mask;` achieves that simply.

The tricky part is to shift `value` to the left by the number of zero bits in `mask` below the set ones. You can write a loop for this.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
unsigned set_bits(unsigned number, unsigned mask, unsigned value) {
    // assuming mask != 0
    number &= ~mask;
    while (!(mask & 1)) {
        value <<= 1;
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    return number | value;
}
```

You can compute the shift value as a multiplier this way: subtracting one from the `mask` sets all its 0 low bits to 1, or-ing this value with `mask` sets all low bits to 1 and xor-ing with `mask` yields a mask with just the low bits set. Adding 1 to this mask gives the power of 2 by which to multiply `value` to shift it in place. This works also if there are no 0 bits in the low order bits of `mask`.

As commented by *aschepler*, `(A ^ (A | B)) == (~A & B)` so the expression `((mask ^ (mask | (mask - 1))) + 1)` can be simplified as `(((mask - 1) & ~mask) + 1)`.

An elegant simplification was provided by *Falk Hüffner*: `(((mask - 1) & ~mask) + 1)` is just `mask & -mask`.

Here is a branchless version using this trick:

```
unsigned set_bits(unsigned number, unsigned mask, unsigned value) {
    return (number & ~mask) | (value * (mask & -mask));
}
```

Making this an inline function may help the compiler generate optimal code for constant mask values.

Comment: `(A ^ (A | B)) == (~A & B)` always. So `return (number & ~mask) | (value * (((mask-1) & ~mask) + 1));`

Comment: @aschepler: good point! I was wondering how to simplify this expression.. Answer updated

Comment: Another way would be to use the non-standard but widely available `ffs` function, or an equivalent intrinsic.  `(number & ~mask) | (value << (ffs(mask)-1))`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @NateEldredge Though `ffs` can't benefit from the assumption that the set bits of `mask` are all contiguous, so might or might not perform better. There's also the six methods at https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear if extreme optimization is needed.

Comment: `(((mask - 1) & ~mask) + 1)` is just `mask & -mask`.

Comment: @FalkHüffner: excellent! bit twiddling at its best כל הכבוד